# converting multiple file ext to pdf from user input not file directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, word-automation

I found this nice, working piece of code on this site but I wanted to make some alterations.

I want to ask a user for a document to upload, but I would like to convert their document to a PDF file if it is not in the PDF format already, such as converting all doc, docx, and excel files.

I got it to work with .doc files, and if I wanted to add more do, would I add them to "*.doc, *.docx, ..."?

Also, currently the program is converting the file if the file is in the same directory. I want it so that it accepts the new directory from the user and saves it to a different directory and not necessarily both in the same place - for example, the program would save from ...\Documents to ...\Uploads.  How could I do this?

Here is the Word to PDF code:

```
private void Word2PDF() {
        //Create a new Microsoft Word application object
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

    //Adding dummy value because c# doesn't have optional arguments
     object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    //Getting list of word files in specified directory
     DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\TestFilestore\\");
    FileInfo[] wordFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.doc");

    word.Visible = false;
    word.ScreenUpdating = false;

        foreach (FileInfo wordFile in wordFiles) {
            //Cast as object for word open method
            Object filename = (Object) wordFile.FullName;

           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
                                               ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                               ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                               ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            doc.Activate();

            object outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
            object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;

            //Save document into pdf format
            doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
                ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

            //close the word document, but leave the word application open.
            //doc has to be cast to type_document so that it will find the correct close method.
            object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
            ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            doc = null;
        }

        //word has to be case to type_application so that it will find the correct quit method.
        ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        word = null;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to implement the SaveDialog() functionality for this..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE i am not sure if i following along what do u exactly mean. Can you clarify just a little - Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate over all your `Word` documents with different extensions you can grab all files from a directory, and filter the list with Linq.

Here an example, you'll need to merge it back into your code in order to get it to work, but you'll get the idea.

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    var oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    // grab all the filenames from your directory (*.*) and filter them with linq
    var wordDocumentFilenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TestFilestore\", "*.*").
                                Where(file => 
                                    file.ToLower().EndsWith("doc") ||
                                    file.ToLower().EndsWith("docx")).  // extend the list to your needs
                                    ToList(); 

    foreach (var wordDocumentFilename in wordDocumentFilenames)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = word.Documents.Open(
            wordDocumentFilename, 
            ref oMissing,
            /* supply the rest of the parameters */);
    }
```

Comment: Great thanks i will go ahead and try this. But what if i want to convert the files entered by the user and not necessarily in a directory? I am asking the user to upload a file and then they browse for a file and then click upload - this is where i will convert the input file from user into pdf and save it to a folder "testStorefile"